# How do I declare constants in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, constants

I have created a basic adventure game in prolog. The player starts with 0 points, and I want the points to increase as the player progresses in the game. How do I do this?

Pardon me if my question sounds stupid, I'm only a beginner in Prolog.

Comment: I wonder how the player can 'progress in the game' without updating the state...You should apply whatever strategy you're already using...

Answer (score 1):

You can add facts at run time using:

```
asserta(...)
assertz(...)
```

`asserta` adds a fact on the top, so using the `cut` i think you can hide the previous value.